# What does the JVM do when 'new' operator initializes the memory using the constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, new-operator

```
RealEstate v = new RealEstate();
```

I have used this `new` keyword with `RealEstate()`. I know `new` allocates memory and initializes the memory using the `RealEstate` class constructor.

What is the JVM doing here?

Comment: I don't feel like this question should have 6 downvotes, most likely downvoters did not understand what the OP was really asking. Hopefully 6 users fought to counter the downvotes.

Comment: yep exactly@Jean-FrançoisSavard

Comment: Your question contains its own answer. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I don't see how does the question contains it own answer ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard The `new` operator initializes memory *by calling the constructor.* There is nothing else to know here.

Comment: @EJP I get that, but the OP was actually asking how is the memory initialized when new operator is called. One could suspect the JVM to do a malloc when encountering a new bytecode instruction for example. Comment by eckes on the answer is the answer as far as I understand.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard That's not what he wrote. He asked how the memory is initialized, not how it is acquired. He says he already knows it 'allocates' memory, so he isn't just misusing a word.

Comment: @EJP To me "How did this operator initialize the memory" is asking for how the allocation is made at a lower level. Hopefully OP will confirm.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard There is a distinct difference between 'allocate' and 'initialize', and the OP is using them in their distinct senses perfectly well. You are just confusing the issue.

Comment: @EJP you're right, my previous comment was unclear - I did mix the terms. But still, I'm quite sure that OP was asking about what was happening at a lower level. I mean, he clearly knows that the new keyword  initialize the memory : *"I know new allocates memory and initializes the memory using constructor"*

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard If he knows that, and he says he does, there is no question here to answer, as I originally said. If the OP is really asking a different question, it is up to him to clarify. Guesswork about what he might really mean is futile, a complete waste of everybody's time. You should not engage in it. It is up to the OP to post a real question.

Comment: I also know new allocates memory and initializes the memory using constructor but  can someone  explain me the working of how "new"initializes the memory?@Jean-FrançoisSavard

Comment: @ShahabKhan "how new initializes the memory", you mean what the JVM does to initialize the memory when it encounter the new bytecode instruction ?

Comment: yes @Jean-FrançoisSavard

Comment: @ShahabKhan If you know these things, *what you asking about?* Despite a lot of discussion it remains completely obscure. `new` initializes the memory *by calling the constructor.* You've said so yourself.

Comment: @ShahabKhan Then you should edit your question to add these words so that everyone understand it as is.

Comment: @EJP I think you have not read the question properly.My mean to say is that what actually Jvm does when new operator initializes memory using constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when JVM executes new key word to create an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501654/what-happens-when-jvm-executes-new-key-word-to-create-an-object)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`new` operator doesn't actually uses the help from constructor to allocate memory. It has nothing to do with constructor. [Basically Java's version of `malloc` is `new`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4404894/2815219)

`new` operator:

- allocates memory for an object
- invokes object constructor
- returns reference to that memory

Constructor is executed separately to perform any operations during initialization, like allocating values to objects and variables. If no Constructor is defined, then compiler will create default constructor and will allocate default values:

---

*The following chart summarizes the default values for several data types.*
*[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*

```
Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
byte            0
short           0
int             0
long            0L
float           0.0f
double          0.0d
char            '\u0000'
String          null
any object      null
boolean         false
```

---

So, `new` operator only allocates memory and returns reference to that memory.

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html):

> The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor.

Comment: No, Java does not use malloc for each object. It is actually much less overhead by basically incrementing a pointer in a region called TLAB (thread local allocation buffer). What happens next is specified in the Java Language Specification, this includes running initializers and constructors of the class hierachy. And before all that the actuall class for the object is constructed and initalied as well. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

Comment: It allocates memory *first*, then calls the constructor, then returns the reference. The default constructor is created by the compiler, not the JVM. You've left out the default values for integer fields, and there is no need to give a default value for `String`, which is just another object. The statement quoted is from the Java Tutorial, not 'the documentation'. The proper thing to cite is the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @EJP I only wanted to point out the major operations that are performed during initialization. That wasn't supposed to be the exact order in which they are performed. Anyways, thanks for notifying, I've updated my answer accordingly. As far as the *default values chart summary* is concerned, it know that isn't any proper documentation, but after all, it is still from [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). so I think it can be trusted.